# SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT ZUSER) in core data

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, ipad, core-data

I'm new in core data I'm converting my sql query to fetch the coredata results but not able to convert this query.

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT ZUSER) AS Users,ZHOUR ,SUM ( ZLIKE) As Likes FROM ZUSERLIKE where ZDAY=28 AND ZMONTH=2 AND ZYEAR=2015 GROUP BY ZHOUR
```

Any expert can help me out the problem I'm facing at COUNT (DISTINCT ZUSER) this point.

Comment: Swift or Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `NSExpression` and `NSExpressionDescription`, something along these lines:

**EDIT** to get COUNT(DISTINCT ZUSER) with group by

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"UserLike"];
// count(ZUSER) NO LONGER REQUIRED:
// NSExpression *userExp = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"user"];
// NSExpression *countUserExp = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:@[userExp]];
// NSExpressionDescription *countUserED = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
// countUserED.name = @"Users";
// countUserED.expression = countUserExp;
// countUserED.expressionResultType = NSInteger64AttributeType;

// sum(ZLIKES):
NSExpression *likesExp = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"likes"];
NSExpression *sumLikesExp = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:@[likesExp]];
NSExpressionDescription *sumLikesED = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
sumLikesED.name = @"Likes";
sumLikesED.expression = sumLikesExp;
sumLikesED.expressionResultType = NSInteger64AttributeType;
// set properties to fetch (REPLACED countUserED with @"user"):
request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"user", @"hour", sumLikesED];
// group by hour AND user
request.propertiesToGroupBy = @[@"hour", @"user"];
// filter using predicate...
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"day == %@ AND month == %@ AND year == %@",@28, @2, @2015];
request.predicate = predicate;
// set result type to dictionary (must do for group by to work)
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
// and execute the query...
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *interimResults = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
// Now need to re-aggregate this by hour:
// First build a predicate with substitution variable:
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hour == $HOUR"];
// Create an array to hold the finalResults
NSMutableArray *finalResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:24];
for (int hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) {
    NSArray *filteredResults = [interimResults filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[filter predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"HOUR" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:hour]}]];
    NSDictionary *aggregatedResults = @{@"Users" : [filteredResults valueForKeyPath:@"@count"],
                                        @"hour" : @(hour),
                                        @"Likes" : [filteredResults valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.Likes"]};
    [finalResults addObject:aggregatedResults];
}

NSLog(@"finalResults is %@", finalResults);
```

(I've guessed your CoreData entity/attribute names based on the underlying SQL in your question, but adjust if I've guessed wrongly, eg. wrong capitals).

Comment: yes but Distinct is missing about which I'm concerned.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  The only suggestion I currently have is to add User to the "group by", and then reaggregate in memory.  But I will think over any nicer solutions.

Comment: `NSFetchRequest` has `returnsDistinctResults` property, but I'm not sure if it will work for this specific case.

Comment: Well, I can't think of a better way, so I will update my answer with code to add the extra "group by" and subsequently aggregate in memory.